# Firebase Database overwrites with setValue

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a Database in Firebase.

this code is in `onCreate()`

```
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseRefUser =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
```

This code is in another method that gets called `onClick`

```
mDatabaseRefUser.child("Chat").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .child(userID).child(uploadID).child("Messages").getRef().push().setValue(new ChatMessage(addMessageEditText.getText().toString(),
                mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()));


mDatabaseRefUser.child("Chat").child(userID)
                .child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(uploadID).child("Messages").getRef().push().setValue(new ChatMessage(addMessageEditText.getText().toString(),
                userEmail));
```

What im trying to do is to add a new value without deleting the previous/existing value everytime the method gets called.

For the moment everytime I click and start the method, the previous/existing value gets removed and the new one gets added. But I want neither to be deleted. I want this the new value to be added aswell. I have tried with `getRef` and `push()` but my data still gets overwritten. What am I doing wrong here?

This is my `JSON` 1st time I call the method

```
"Users" : {
"Chat" : {
  "Xta3jwm4yLQWaJBypMBFt2esiOr2" : {
    "xfqAFlRpbUZRlZb76svN5FUtbU93" : {
      "-LCvIA_9L1Y9rjkm96Aj" : {
        "Messages" : {
          "-LCvqDidnNqQ8ALZhDud" : {
            "messageText" : "Very good",
            "messageTime" : 1526791230552,
            "messageUser" : "mama@mama.com"
          }
        },
        "chatAgainstUserEmail" : "mama2@mama.com",
        "chatAgainstUserID" : "xfqAFlRpbUZRlZb76svN5FUtbU93",
        "uploadID" : "-LCvIA_9L1Y9rjkm96Aj",
        "userEmail" : "mama@mama.com",
        "userID" : "Xta3jwm4yLQWaJBypMBFt2esiOr2"
      }
    }
  },
  "xfqAFlRpbUZRlZb76svN5FUtbU93" : {
    "Xta3jwm4yLQWaJBypMBFt2esiOr2" : {
      "-LCvIA_9L1Y9rjkm96Aj" : {
        "Messages" : {
          "-LCvqDigI8ZwHDYuPhw9" : {
            "messageText" : "Very good",
            "messageTime" : 1526791230555,
            "messageUser" : "mama2@mama.com"
          }
        },
        "chatAgainstUserEmail" : "mama@mama.com",
        "chatAgainstUserID" : "Xta3jwm4yLQWaJBypMBFt2esiOr2",
        "uploadID" : "-LCvIA_9L1Y9rjkm96Aj",
        "userEmail" : "mama2@mama.com",
        "userID" : "xfqAFlRpbUZRlZb76svN5FUtbU93"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my `JSON` when I call it for the 2nd time

```
"Users" : {
"Chat" : {
  "Xta3jwm4yLQWaJBypMBFt2esiOr2" : {
    "xfqAFlRpbUZRlZb76svN5FUtbU93" : {
      "-LCvIA_9L1Y9rjkm96Aj" : {
        "Messages" : {
          "-LCvr0zoHOPxsKOVJzeu" : {
            "messageText" : "Very good 2nd call",
            "messageTime" : 1526791440547,
            "messageUser" : "mama@mama.com"
          }
        },
        "chatAgainstUserEmail" : "mama2@mama.com",
        "chatAgainstUserID" : "xfqAFlRpbUZRlZb76svN5FUtbU93",
        "uploadID" : "-LCvIA_9L1Y9rjkm96Aj",
        "userEmail" : "mama@mama.com",
        "userID" : "Xta3jwm4yLQWaJBypMBFt2esiOr2"
      }
    }
  },
  "xfqAFlRpbUZRlZb76svN5FUtbU93" : {
    "Xta3jwm4yLQWaJBypMBFt2esiOr2" : {
      "-LCvIA_9L1Y9rjkm96Aj" : {
        "Messages" : {
          "-LCvr0zrh8wQ2WurUezs" : {
            "messageText" : "Very good 2nd call",
            "messageTime" : 1526791440550,
            "messageUser" : "mama2@mama.com"
          }
        },
        "chatAgainstUserEmail" : "mama@mama.com",
        "chatAgainstUserID" : "Xta3jwm4yLQWaJBypMBFt2esiOr2",
        "uploadID" : "-LCvIA_9L1Y9rjkm96Aj",
        "userEmail" : "mama2@mama.com",
        "userID" : "xfqAFlRpbUZRlZb76svN5FUtbU93"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried without the getRef() and push() but it still doesn't solve my problem

Comment: mDatabaseRefUser is DatabaseReference! right?
Could you please include your database screenshot in question?

Comment: yes, its DatabaseReference, why?, Sorry my computer is old I can't include screenshot

Comment: The `.getRef()` call is not needed, and in fact, might be harmful. Remove it and see if the problem disappears. If the problem persists: show the JSON that you have before you execute this code, and then again the JSON after executing the code. That way we can see what happens.

Comment: Okay I have done it now

Comment: this was done without the `.getRef()`, only `push()`, but it doesn't matter since both gave me same result unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

try use **.add**

```
.collection("Messages").add(ChatMessage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS! " + documentReference.getId());
                    }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
                }
            });
```

Comment: I don't understand. Where do I use .add

Comment: Did you understand my problem?

Comment: This .setValue will replace value in your database

Comment: yes I know that it replaces my value, but how can I solve this issue? I don't fully understand ur answer

Comment: Your "Messages" is a collection in database, right?

Comment: yes I guess, but I don't see any .collection suggestion

Comment: Structod DB is .collection.document().collection.document()... You need check your data structure for it.

Comment: @DiegoVenâncio: jonny is using the Firebase Realtime Database. The `collection()` and `document()` methods only exist in Cloud Firestore, which is a different database.

Comment: frank van puffelen is correct. I am using realtime database